# I have A procedure I need to capture error massage if count = 0 then fetch the record else if count > 0 the capture error massage in error table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
PROCEDURE p_get_empdetails(pcu_scheme_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS  
BEGIN


    -- To Select scheme_ref,scheme_cat and quote_ref
    OPEN pcu_scheme_info FOR
        SELECT emp_ref
              ,emp_cat
              ,emp_quote_ref
        FROM emp_reset_id e
        WHERE estimated_quote_expiry_date <= lpcd_system_date
        AND q.quote_ref IN (SELECT DISTINCT qrc.quote_ref
                            FROM nb005 nb, 
                                 emp_reset_id e
                            WHERE nb.qteref = e.emp_quote_ref
                            AND nb.pcsstg <> 51);                
END p_get_scheme_details;
```

I need to use below query to fetch record count =0 or count> 0

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM nb005 nb JOIN emp_reset_id e ON nb.qteref = qrc.emp_quote_ref
WHERE nb.pcsstg=51;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are you expecting to run the query? And exactly what should happen if you get records or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the procedure to finish without any errors when count > 0 and end successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_get_empdetails(pcu_scheme_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
number v_count := 0;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) into 
  FROM nb005 nb JOIN emp_reset_id e ON nb.qteref = qrc.emp_quote_ref
  WHERE nb.pcsstg=51;

  IF v_count > 0 THEN

  --This is where you capture error message in error table.

  ELSE
  -- To Select scheme_ref,scheme_cat and quote_ref
  OPEN pcu_scheme_info FOR
      SELECT emp_ref
            ,emp_cat
            ,emp_quote_ref
      FROM emp_reset_id e
      WHERE estimated_quote_expiry_date <= lpcd_system_date
      AND q.quote_ref IN (SELECT DISTINCT qrc.quote_ref
                          FROM nb005 nb, 
                               emp_reset_id e
                          WHERE nb.qteref = e.emp_quote_ref
                          AND nb.pcsstg <> 51);                
  END IF;
END p_get_scheme_details;
```

If you want the procedure to fail when the count is > 0, but still want to insert records into the error table (my preferred way):

```
CREATE OR PROCEDURE p_get_empdetails(pcu_scheme_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
v_count number := 0;
v_excep exception;
v_err_msg varchar2(1000) := '';
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) into 
    FROM nb005 nb JOIN emp_reset_id e ON nb.qteref = qrc.emp_quote_ref
    WHERE nb.pcsstg=51;

    IF v_count > 0 THEN

    raise v_excep;

    ELSE
    -- To Select scheme_ref,scheme_cat and quote_ref
    OPEN pcu_scheme_info FOR
        SELECT emp_ref
              ,emp_cat
              ,emp_quote_ref
        FROM emp_reset_id e
        WHERE estimated_quote_expiry_date <= lpcd_system_date
        AND q.quote_ref IN (SELECT DISTINCT qrc.quote_ref
                            FROM nb005 nb, 
                                 emp_reset_id e
                            WHERE nb.qteref = e.emp_quote_ref
                            AND nb.pcsstg <> 51);                
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_excep THEN
      v_err_msg := 'v_count was greater than 0. '||CHR(10);
      --This is where you capture error message in error table.
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20555,v_err_msg||'Error: ' || to_char ( SQLCODE ) || ': ' || SQLERRM || '. Backtrace Result: ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20502,v_err_msg||'Error: ' || to_char ( SQLCODE ) || ': ' || SQLERRM || '. Backtrace Result: ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);

END p_get_scheme_details;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks  but i  don't  want to fail if count > 0 it should be insert a Emp code in error table .

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a cursor in the pocedure you are using. 
 
Then use a record to fetch the results from the query that is declared in the cursor. 
 
You could for example even loop through all lines and process then. 
 
For example:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CursorName IS 
        SELECT  COUNT(*) ColumnOne 
        FROM    TableA 
        WHERE   Name = 'Me';

    RecordNumber CursorName%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN 
    -- Fetch the records from the cursor. 
    OPEN CursorName; 
    LOOP
        -- Line by line 
        FETCH CursorName INTO RecordNumber;

        -- Do something with the record. 
        IF RecordNumber.ColumnOne = 0 THEN
            -- Do something with the record. 
        END IF;

        EXIT WHEN CursorName %NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CursorName;

END;
/
```

I don't have a database by hand to test my code, but I think this should do.